# efficient prepending to array

Tags: arrays, arduino, embedded, keil

I am porting one of the well known libraries for arduino called `i2cdevlib` to my embedded system. And I meet a problem, actually this time is far from being the first one, when function interface looks like:

```
void function(uint8_t dev_addr, uint8_t reg_addr, uint8_t *data, uint8_t len);
```

and what I need to do is firstly to write `dev_addr` to i2c bus then `reg_addr` and then `data`. But i2c driver(I use one from Keil MDK packs) function which is used to send data into i2c bus has definition like this:

```
void send_i2c(uint8_t dev_addr, uint8_t *data, uint8_t len);
```

And because of some i2c properties I can not call it sequentially. So every time when `function` is called I have to create new array, set first item to `reg_addr` and then `memcpy data` into it which looks awful and seems not to be very efficient(to be honest there is very little data flow when working with these sensors but nevertheless...). However I can not see another solution  except for modifying i2c driver or writing new one but I don't feel like rewriting sustainable and tested driver just because of one function.

So is there any way to improve this solution without doing this?

Comment: Given that existing interface, I'm not sure there is another way (other than pushing the responsibility onto the caller of `function`).  If this isn't a bottleneck, and you can encapsulate this grossness into a single function, then I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I am not able to push it onto `function` caller because `function` interface is dictated by `i2cdevlib` library.

Comment: So you're caught between two fixed function prototypes, and you control neither the outer caller nor the inner callee?

Comment: @Medinoc yes, that's right.

Comment: "well known" might be a better description for a library that "famous" - I wouldn't go that far.

Comment: @Clifford thanks, replaced it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with how I2CDevLib is implemented. It should not force the user to specify a register address, because the I2C protocol does not mandate having an 8-bit register address to write to. Most devices do, but some might not.

What you need to do ultimately is send the register address then the payload without sending any stop bit. You should look if Keil MDK has an I2C function that allows you to send data byte per byte without interrupting transmission. This way your function could send the register address then each byte of the payload separately.

This introduces the overhead of multiple function calls, unless those calls are inlined by the compiler. If those calls are simple they should be inlined, but there is no guarantee they will be.

The other thing you could do is dig deep into the manual for your MCU, find the I2C registers, how they work and implement your own I2C routines. But this requires a lot more work on your end.